# Does a mocked method's code actually run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, ruby-mocha

Hi I'm using Mocha for a Rails project. I'm new to TDD so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

If I have this

```
@client.expects(:create_config).once.returns(true)
```

then am I right in assuming that the code in `create_config()` won't be run and instead true will just be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used mocha, but this is indeed the case for all mocking frameworks i've worked with

Comment: Never used mocha, but that behavior is kind of the entire *point* of mock objects...

Comment: I wasnt sure if mocks just asserted whether or not a certain method was called or not or if they also bypassed the actual methods code as well. I knew stubs existed to do the latter so thought perhaps mocks didnt do that.

Answer (score 0):

Both expects and stubs prevent execution of the specified method.  The difference is that expects creates an assertion that causes the test to fail if the method isn't called, and stubs doesn't create any assertion.